# why one of the code is not working on codechef?

Tags: java, sub-array

Here is the problem statement: https://www.codechef.com/DAY4DA002/problems/CHEFSUB

Problem description

> You are given an array *A* of *N* integers: A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, ..., A<sub>N</sub>. You need to find a longest contiguous subarray in the array such that each integer in this subarray is an even integer, and output its length. A contiguous subarray is of the form A<sub>i</sub>, A<sub>i+1</sub>, ..., A<sub>j</sub>, for some *i* and *j*.

[input parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMhvG.png)

The code specified below is giving the desired output when i provide input manually but on CodeChef none of the test cases are getting passed

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    int j = 0;
    while(t-- > 0)
    {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int k = 1; k < n; k++)
        {
            j = k-1;
            if(arr[j]%2==0 && arr[k]%2==0)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count+1);
    }
    return;
}
```

Input:

```
3
4
1 2 2 4
3
2 4 6
5
2 3 2 2 5
```

Output:

```
3
3
2
```

The above code is providing me the above correct answers when I run it on other IDEs

Now the below given code works for *CodeChef* and it passes all the test cases

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    try {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        while (t-->0)
        {
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int count = 0;
            int res = -1 ;
            int[] a=new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (a[i]%2==0)
                {
                    count++;
                    res = Math.max(count ,res);
                }
                else {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what is the issue with first code and why it is not working on CodeChef?

Comment: "[Do not](https://www.codechef.com/codeofconduct) ask or discuss any aspect of any CodeChefs’ problem during an ongoing contest on any other platform, online or offline." I don't have access to the web site so I can't tell whether this is an active contest.

Comment: @RaymondChen Although that might be true, Stack Overflow does not care about the limitations or requirements of other sites.

Comment: Your code gives incorrect answers for other sequences, such as: "2 2 1 2 2 2 1" -> 4

Comment: If one of your input arrays contains only two elements and both of them are odd, then your code will print 1 (one). Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: thanks, @Abra and  for pointing out the particulate case

Comment: thanks, @akarnokd and for pointing out the particulate case